# nginx SSL error

Tags: ssl, nginx

When I run `sbin/nginx -t`  I get the following error

```
[emerg]: the "ssl" parameter requires ngx_http_ssl_module in /root/cloudfoundry/.deployments/devbox/deploy/nginx/nginx-0.8.54/conf/nginx.conf:98
configuration file /root/cloudfoundry/.deployments/devbox/deploy/nginx/nginx-0.8.54/conf/nginx.conf test failed
```

Comment: Can you paste your ssl config ?

Comment: Cloud Foundry can help you with their service.

Comment: It looks like your nginx haven't been built with ngx_http_ssl_module

Answer (score 9):

It looks like your nginx haven't been built with ngx_http_ssl_module. See the output of `nginx -V` if there is no `--with-http_ssl_module` parameter then ssl will not work

Comment: how to build with ssl then?

Comment: Download openssl: `wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.1t.tar.gz`  Go to nginx source folder and: `./configure --with-http_ssl_module --with-openssl=/home/ubuntu/openssl-1.0.1t`
`make -j2`
`make install`

Comment: nginx source installation:  https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/install/

Comment: dont forget to yum install openssl-devel